# xshell: failed to load update data file - possible client/data version mismatch

Tags: xshell

[image]

After updated and restarted, xshell prompted the dialog as above

Answer (score 0):

Solution: no need to uninstall, just rerun the same version of the xshell installer, it will fix it for you.